# python unittest ，why is the log empty?

Tags: python, python-unittest

[image: screenshot]

When I run test_case.py, the created log is empty. Why is this?

```
import os
caselist=os.listdir(r'C:\Users\jack\Desktop\auto_test\test_case')
for a in caselist:
    s=a.split('.')[1] 
    print(s)
    if s=='py':
        os.system(r'C:\Users\jack\Desktop\auto_test\test_case\%s 1>>log.txt 2>&1' % a)
```

Comment: does it `print(s)`?

Comment: Why don't you use py.test or unitttest frameworks? This implementation looks very "hacky".

Comment: Also there's other flaws in the code, i.e: If your file has 2 dots it's not gonna work as you expect (ex: file.name.py).
And you are not specifying the interpreter to run the code, plus calling os.system is usually a bad practice.

Comment: @yosemite_k it did not print. The txt is empty, the script located to baidu.py, but did not run.It make me confused .

Comment: @danielfranca  I did this according the  tutorial ,and want to know why it is.

Comment: @danielfranca  first my file' name is test_case.py， it did not have two dots. It did locate to baidu.py in script, but it did not run baidu.py. This is the problem ,but i do not know the reason.